# Is it possible to apply type erasure to returned value in protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, types, compilation, protocols

Okay now, the title might be a little bit ambiguous, but basically, what I'm trying to achieve is the following:
Let's say I have two classes that I use to fetch data from backend and they both cache the fetched data, thus, they both have an `invalidateCache()` method. Since they are used for data fetching, each of them also have a method `fetch()` that returns different kind of objects:

```
class UserManager {
    ...
    func invalidateCache() {
        ...
    }
    func fetch() -> [User] {
        ...
        return users
    }
}

class PostManager {
    ...
    func invalidateCache() {
        ...
    }
    func fetch() -> [Post] {
        ...
        return posts
    }
}
```

Then I have one base view controller and two inherited view controllers (e.g., `UsersViewController` and `PostsViewController`), which I actually use. These two view controllers use corresponding entity managers. I want to have some generic protocol which will be a type of a property in base view controller and each of inherited ones would have specific implementations, something like this:

```
protocol EntityManager<Result>: class {
    func invalidateCache()
    func fetch() -> [Result]
}

class UserManager: EntityManager<User> {
    ...
    func fetch() -> [User] {
        ...
    }
}

class PostManager: EntityManager<Post> {
    ...
    func fetch() -> [Post] {
        ...
    }
}


class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var manager: EntityManager?
    override func viewDidDisappear() {
        manager?.invalidateCache()
    }
}

class UserViewController: BaseViewController {
    var users: [User]?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = UserManager()
        users = manager?.fetch()
    }
}

class PostViewController: BaseViewController {
    var posts: [Post]?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = PostManager()
        posts = manager?.fetch()
    }
}
```

I tried to apply type erasure but didn't succeed in any ways (I suspect that I don't fully understand spheres of application of type erasure). As far as I understand, swift compiler requires that types must be univocal during compile time, I just don't understand why there's ambiguity in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You would need User and Post to have something in common. For example,

```
protocol Fetchable { }
class User: Fetchable { }
class Post: Fetchable { }

class Manageable<T> {
    func fetch() -> [T] { return [] }
}
class UserManager: Manageable<User> {
    override func fetch() -> [User] { return [] }
}
class PostManager: Manageable<Post> {
    override func fetch() -> [Post] { return [] }
}

let users = UserManager().fetch()
print("users=\(users)")
let posts = PostManager().fetch()
print("posts=\(posts)")
```